# Laravel retrieve data from different tables and show in blade

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I have 2 table A and B

A: id, b_id (which is the value of B's id & share many query rows), name, balance
B: id, country, state, age

In my view, I want to retrieve the data of A which has some specific id from B

Like: @foreach ($B_TABLE->id as $b_id)
{{ $b_id->sum('balance') }} <--- In this I want to retrieve the total sum of every 'balance' column from A table which has the id of $b_data in b_id column

What should be done in the Model/Controller to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this Eloquent query with join:

```
$query = TableB::join('table_a', 'table_a.table_two_id', '=', 'table_b.id')
        ->select('table_b.id', \DB::raw("SUM(table_a.balance) as total_balance"))
        ->where('table_a.table_two_id', $id)
        ->groupBy('table_a.table_two_id')
        ->get();
```

Comment: Isn't "hasMany" or "belongsToMany" recommended other than this? Is there any performance difference if I use this instead belongsTo method?

Comment: Since you need a sum of columns and group by does not work very well with eager loading and relations in Laravel.

Comment: Thanks for the info.

Is it not possible to calculate the sum in blade instead of in Controller?

Comment: It is possible you can use collection.